# How to click websites automatically on google, using Delphi WebBrowser Component

Tags: delphi, tchromium

I am developing a software using Delphi. I have following elements.

1 Webbrowser

1 button

2 edit box.

Edit1 : input for a keyword

Edit2 : input for a website

When I click the "button" it searches the entered keyword on Google.

If the website (which has been entered into the edit box) is found in the results, it then enters to that site

The problem is when I check the google analytics It shows the traffic source as a direct not as a organic.

I clicked to the website manually and it showed the traffic source as a organic.

So my question is what needs to be done to show the traffic as a organic. Do I need to find coordinates for the result and redirect Cursor Position to there?

Edit: How Can I test if the link is "actually clicked" not "redirected" ?

Comment: This sounds like something that could be used to click adverts, etc. Am I the only one uncomfortable with it?

Comment: Well I am newbie on programming. I just want to learn how to do it. I am not writing a virus or something. I know that there is a software called jingling which using for adverts clicks. But What I am trying to do is nothing like it. I will appreciate it if you can advise me how to do it.